# How to change all json value values ​to 0 python

Tags: json, discord.py

How can my python code change all json values ​​to 0.

Code

```
    str(ctx.author.id): score
```

This is the result I want:

```
    str(ctx.author.id): 4
    str(ctx.author.id): 3
```

str(ctx.author.id) is It can change at any time.

str(ctx.author.id) is Consists of 18 digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all JSON values to be 0? then why are you giving 3, 4 in example

Anyways here is how you will do it

```py
import json

with open("filename.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for i in data:
    data[i] = 0

with open("filename.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```